# converting some rows into columns in R

Tags: regex, r, row

I have a table with 1 columns and I want to extract one among the other elements in rows and insert into new column.
lets say my table: `df`

```
      V1
elements-of-01-to-20
ACTCTGCGACHCHAHAATT
elements-of-21-to-30
ACTAGCTATTATCGATATT
elements-of-31-to-40
CCCTTATATTGGAGCTACT
```

my desired result:

```
       V1                   V2
elements-of-01-to-20   ACTCTGCGACHCHAHAATT
elements-of-21-to-20   ACTAGCTATTATCGATATT
elements-of-31-to-20   CCCTTATATTGGAGCTACT
elements-of-31-to-40   CCCTTATATTGGAGCTACT
```

***edited***:
thanks for all replies. my second question is what if my dataset has multiple sequences followed by specific term like `elements-of`:

```
   V1               => result =>         V1                   v2
elements-of-01-to-20            elements-of-01-to-20  ACTCTGCGACHCHAHAATTAGGGGATGCTGATTTAGTA
ACTCTGCGACHCHAHAATT             elements-of-21-to-30  ACTAGCTATTATCGATATT
AGGGGATGCTGATTTAGTA
elements-of-21-to-30
ACTAGCTATTATCGATATT
```

Comment: yes sir, one specific term like `element-of` is common between all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the pattern is the same as in the example

```
 indx <- c(TRUE, FALSE)
 data.frame(V1=df$V1[indx], V2=df$V1[!indx])
 #                  V1                  V2
 #1 elements-of-01-to-20 ACTCTGCGACHCHAHAATT
 #2 elements-of-21-to-30 ACTAGCTATTATCGATATT
 #3 elements-of-31-to-40 CCCTTATATTGGAGCTACT
```

#### Update

Based on the updated dataset

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[,list(V1=V1[1], V2=paste(V1[-1], collapse='')),
        by= list(indx=cumsum(grepl('^[^A-Z]', df$V1)))][, indx:=NULL][]

 #                   V1                                     V2
 #1: elements-of-01-to-20 ACTCTGCGACHCHAHAATTAGGGGATGCTGATTTAGTA
 #2: elements-of-21-to-30                    ACTAGCTATTATCGATATT
```

#### New data

```
 df <- structure(list(V1 = c("elements-of-01-to-20", "ACTCTGCGACHCHAHAATT", 
 "AGGGGATGCTGATTTAGTA", "elements-of-21-to-30", "ACTAGCTATTATCGATATT"
 )), .Names = "V1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: smart way, I like it. But my actual data is more complicate. it is not exactly one after one. All those which start with the term `elements` should separate from other rows.

Comment: @Cina Okay, You should have showed an example that mimics your dataset.

Answer (score 2):

If that is just a fasta file then look at the Biostrings package. You could do it this way too

```
MySeq <- data.frame("Name" = df$V1[(seq(1, length(df$V1), by=2)],
"Seq" = df$V1[(seq(2, length(df$V1), by=2)],
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: yes it is fasta file and i really need to convert into proper continuance sequence in two columns. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way using `grepl`:

```
#dummy data
df <- read.table(text="      V1
elements-of-01-to-20
ACTCTGCGACHCHAHAATT
elements-of-21-to-30
ACTAGCTATTATCGATATT
elements-of-31-to-40
CCCTTATATTGGAGCTACT",
                 as.is=TRUE,header=TRUE)
#result
cbind(df[ grepl("elements",df$V1), "V1"],
      df[ !grepl("elements",df$V1), "V1"])

#output
#      [,1]                   [,2]                 
# [1,] "elements-of-01-to-20" "ACTCTGCGACHCHAHAATT"
# [2,] "elements-of-21-to-30" "ACTAGCTATTATCGATATT"
# [3,] "elements-of-31-to-40" "CCCTTATATTGGAGCTACT"
```

Comment: it is good way, could you explain more about the part `grepl`? thanks

Comment: @zx8754 +1 looks like this would be more general, but not sure because the OP mentioned the dataset to be `complex`

Answer (score 1):

Try (using traditional programming methods):

```
ndf = data.frame(V1="", V2="", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
i=1
while(i<nrow(df)){
    ndf[(nrow(ndf)+1),]=c(df[i,1], df[(i+1),1])
    i=i+2
}
ndf[-1,]
                    V1                  V2
2 elements-of-01-to-20 ACTCTGCGACHCHAHAATT
3 elements-of-21-to-30 ACTAGCTATTATCGATATT
4 elements-of-31-to-40 CCCTTATATTGGAGCTACT
```